# How to send back json data with status(204).send() without refreshing the page in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, express-handlebars

I am working in nodejs project with handlebars. I am a beginner in nodejs. I just want to send back some data(it could be a json object) to handlebars template after POST request on the same page without refreshing the page. But I don't know how to do this.

This is the part of code but not the entire code:

```
router.post('/post/team', (req, res)=>{
    const newTeamPostQuery = newteampost({
        totalOvers: req.body.totalOvers,
        currentMatch: true,
        teamOne: [
            {
                name: req.body.teamOne,
                over: 0
            }
        ],
        teamTwo: [
            {
                name: req.body.teamTwo,
                over: 0
            }
        ]
    });

    newTeamPostQuery.save().then(savedPost=>{
        res.status(204).send({data: savedPost});
    }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

I don't want to refresh the page. When I use this `res.json({data: newTeamPostQuery});` then it refreshes the page to this `/post/team` route and show the json data on the page.

I am using handlebars to show data like this:
`{{#if data.currentMatch}} data.totalOvers {{else}} Overs {{/if}}`

I am using mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do `form` `post` request from `handlebars` template. Include JS file in your `handlebars` template and you need to call `ajax` `post` to that URI `'/post/team'` and you will get back the response in your `ajax` response. That's how your page won't refresh and you will get data without refreshing the page.

Using jQuery Ajax Post request.

```
//In your js code collect value of 'totalOvers','teamOne' and 'teamTwo' from HTML 
//field using jquery with the help of HTML ID and call the ajax as following 

$.ajax({
            url: '/post/team',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({totalOvers: '5', teamOne: '2', teamTwo:'4'}),
            success: function (response) {
               //you will get server response here
               //do, what you need to do
            },            
        });
```

Comment: Is there any way to POST data without form submit just like we do in javascript Onclick() and get input values seperately ??

Comment: Use jQuery to get the value of every field and POST data as a JSON object using an Ajax call.

To get data using jQuery go to this link and check. 
[link](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box-using-jquery.php)

Comment: how i can make URL ```/post/team``` without nodejs router ?
we always use ```get``` or ```post``` to make a URL and write code inside it. If i use ajax then how i can work with Schema just like i did in my code above on line 2...
i am using mongodb in my project.

Comment: Please go to the link and follow this tutorial. I hope, after that, you can understand the total process. 
Click this [link](https://grokonez.com/node-js/integrate-nodejs-express-jquery-ajax-post-get-bootstrap-view)

Comment: thanks, i have understand the whole procedure
actually i was in mess. Now its OK

Answer (score 0):

Alright so as I am thinking you are getting this Data from your HTML

let's suppose you have `<input type=text id='username>` 
after that you have the submit button, now you don't need to make a submit form 
just include js file at the end of your html file `<script src='main.js'></script>` 
inside main.js

```
document.getElementById('buttonID).addEventListener('click,()=>{
    let username = document.detElementById('buttonID')
    // make post request with ajax to send that data
})
```

inside your post request do whatever you like with that data you got back 
you could have empty HTML element and just change their values with that data